# How do I get Wireshark to filter for a specific web host?

Tags: wireshark

I'm using Wireshark on OSX, but I can't make any sense out of the filtering system.

I have this filter set up:

[image]

But when I hit that server, I don't see anything show up in the capture log. If I remove the filter, I see all sorts of network traffic. The network request I am doing is to

https://lowdown.secure.omnis.com

from an iOS application in the iOS simulator. The service receives the request, and I get a response. But I don't know how to filter these out of all the noise in Wireshark.

Comment: You can filter for the IP (ping the server to get it) with `ip.addr == 123.123.2.1`. Dont you have to use `==` instead of `eq`?

Comment: That works, Jake. Drop it in as an answer. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can filter on a HTTP host on multiple levels. At the application layer, you can specify a [display filter](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkBuildDisplayFilterSection.html) for the HTTP Host header:

```
http.host == "example.com"
```

At the transport layer, you can specify a port using this display filter:

```
tcp.port == 80
```

At the network layer, you can limit the results to an IP address using this display filter:

```
ip.addr == 93.184.216.34
```

These display filters can also be combined:

```
ip.addr == 93.184.216.34 and tcp.port == 80
```

Finally you can set a [*capture filter*](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCapCaptureFilterSection.html) which controls the data that gets saved to a capture file. Capture filters must be set before capturing, you can open a dialog for this by double-clicking the interface name when no capture is active. This one causes a lookup of `example.com` and returns IP packets matching that host:

```
host example.com
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I get back to it, I'll test this then accept the answer. :)